# Getting Unique records based on a column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Looking for a way to get all of the related records for a resource and have them all distinct by a column(`:author_id`) and then ordered by the `created_at` column.
There are several similar questions on here, however I do not see any that include this ordering that I need. Trying to avoid converting to an array.

```
  Post.find(id)
   .ratings
    .select(
     "DISTINCT on (author_id) author_id, rating_number, created_at, id")
      .order(created_at: :desc)
```

The first part works, but when introduce the order, it gives me an error to add created_at into the DISTINCT clause. It then works however I then get records that are not distinct on just `:author_id`.

Comment: What's `poster_id`? isn't it `post_id`?

Comment: @SebastianPalma I'm guessing `poster_id` is a reference to the user that created the post. It makes a lot more sense than having a `post_id` column unless your one of those people that think that prefixing your column names with the table name is fun.

Comment: poster_id is a reference to an author, I have updated the question and columns here for clarity.